# Use JS library in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use [Ether JS](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/index.html) in my Flutter application. I know that it is not directly supported and even the existing implementations are not really well documented.

Is there any way I can use this library in my Flutter application for Android and iOS? Any other alternative suggestion is also welcome.

I have tried [js.dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) but could not figure out how to use it. I am not even sure if it is the right choice for this scenario.

I have also tried [Flutter WebView Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-readme-tab-).

```
plugin.evalJavascript(
    'function add(a,b){return a+b;}add(2,3);'
).then((s) {
    print(s);
}
```

This function rightly returns `5` as the response. But I do not understand how to use the EtherJS library like this.

I am a noob with Flutter, Dart and JS. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: plugin.evalJavascript(
    'function add(a,b){return a+b;}add(2,3);'
).then((s) {
    print(s);
}
that is not work with me please add full code thanks :)

Comment: @Mahmoudsalaheldiensaber That was not the problem code. There was no point in posting the complete code of something that was already working for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Honestly, if you're new to Flutter, Dart, and JS you are going to have some trouble with this unless you're willing to invest a fair amount of time. It does depend on what exactly you're trying to make with the Ether JS library, but in general you're going to have a hard time integrating it with flutter. There is an [Ethereum package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ethereum) but it seems much narrower in scope than the ether.js library you've been looking at - it mostly seems focused on communication with the RPC api rather than dealing with wallets etc.

If you're dead set on using Flutter, your best bet would be to use [Android](https://web3j.io/) & [iOS](https://github.com/MercuryProtocol/web3.swift) specific libraries to do the actual ethereum stuff and to communicate through [Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to a common api in your dart code. This could be a significant undertaking depending on how much of the API you need to expose, especially for someone new to flutter/dart and possibly to android/ios development as well. This will be much more performant than communicating back and forth with javascript running in a webview though, and realistically probably easier to code as well because flutter doesn't really have any good mechanisms for calling js code right now.

There is another option - to use a different client UI framework entirely. [React native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) might do everything you need and has the advantage of being in Javascript so it can most likely integrate the Ether.js library easily, although I can't guarantee that it will actually fully support the ether.js library (its runtime might not have the necessary crypto extensions for example).

Comment: Platform channels look like what I would need in this case. I have some development experience in native Android and iOS. This should be something I can work with.

Comment: Ah okay good, it's always hard to know what to suggest when you don't know someone's background. Platform channels (well, and Method channels)) arelatively straightforward once you get used to how it works. Best of luck!

Answer (score 22):

I eventually solved this by using Platform channels as suggested by [rmtmckenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2927226/rmtmckenzie) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330589/6891637).

I downloaded the JS file and saved it to `android/app/src/main/res/raw/ether.js` and `ios/runner/ether.js` for Android and iOS respectively.

### Installing dependencies

#### Android

Add [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore) as a dependency in app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.LiquidPlayer:LiquidCore:0.5.0'
```

#### iOS

For iOS I used the [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) which is part of the SDK.

### Platform Channel

In my case, I needed to create a Wallet based on a Mnemonic (look up BIP39) I pass in into the JS function. For this, I created a Platform channel which passes in the Mnemonic (which is basically of type String) as an argument and will return a JSON object when done.

```dart
Future<dynamic> getWalletFromMnemonic({@required String mnemonic}) {
  return platform.invokeMethod('getWalletFromMnemonic', [mnemonic]);
}
```

### Android Implementation (Java)

Inside `MainActivity.java` add this after this line

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
```

```java
String CHANNEL = "UNIQUE_CHANNEL_NAME";

new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
    new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
            if (methodCall.method.equals("getWalletFromMnemonic")) {
                ArrayList<Object> args = (ArrayList<Object>) methodCall.arguments;
                String mnemonic = (String) args.get(0);

                JSObject walletFromMnemonic = getWalletFromMnemonic(mnemonic);
                if (walletFromMnemonic == null) {
                    result.error("Could not create", "Wallet generation failed", null);
                    return;
                }

                String privateKey = walletFromMnemonic.property("privateKey").toString();
                String address = walletFromMnemonic.property("address").toString();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("privateKey", privateKey);
                map.put("address", address);

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(map);

                result.success(obj.toString());

            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Declare the following methods which perform the actual action of interacting with the JS library and returning the result to the platform channel.

```
@Nullable
@VisibleForTesting
private JSObject getWalletFromMnemonic(String mnemonic) {
    JSContext jsContext = getJsContext(getEther());
    JSObject wallet = getWalletObject(jsContext);

    if (wallet == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!wallet.hasProperty("fromMnemonic")) {
        return null;
    }

    JSFunction walletFunction = wallet.property("fromMnemonic").toObject().toFunction();
    return walletFunction.call(null, mnemonic).toObject();
}

@Nullable
@VisibleForTesting
private JSObject getWalletObject(JSContext context) {
    JSObject jsEthers = context.property("ethers").toObject();
    if (jsEthers.hasProperty("Wallet")) {
        return jsEthers.property("Wallet").toObject();
    }
    return null;
}

@VisibleForTesting
String getEther() {
    String s = "";
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ether);
    try {
        s = IOUtils.toString(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        s = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
    return s;
}

@VisibleForTesting
JSContext getJsContext(String code) {
    JSContext context = new JSContext();
    context.evaluateScript(code);
    return context;
}
```

### iOS Implementation (Swift)

Add the following lines in `AppDelegate.swift` inside the `override application` method.

```
final let methodChannelName: String = "UNIQUE_CHANNEL_NAME"
let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: methodChannelName, binaryMessenger: controller)

methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult)-> Void in
    if call.method == "getWalletFromMnemonic" {
        guard let mnemonic = call.arguments as? [String] else {
            return
        }

        if let wallet = self.getWalletFromMnemonic(mnemonic: mnemonic[0]) {
            result(wallet)
        } else {
            result("Invalid")
        }
    }
})
```

Add the logic to interact with the JavaScriptCore.

```
private func getWalletFromMnemonic(mnemonic: String) -> Dictionary<String, String>? {
    let PRIVATE_KEY = "privateKey"
    let ADDRESS = "address"

    guard let jsContext = self.initialiseJS(jsFileName: "ether") else { return nil }
    guard let etherObject = jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("ethers") else { return nil }
    guard let walletObject = etherObject.objectForKeyedSubscript("Wallet") else { return nil }


    guard let walletFromMnemonicObject = walletObject.objectForKeyedSubscript("fromMnemonic") else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let wallet = walletFromMnemonicObject.call(withArguments: [mnemonic]) else { return nil }
    guard let privateKey = wallet.forProperty(PRIVATE_KEY)?.toString() else { return nil }
    guard let address = wallet.forProperty(ADDRESS)?.toString() else { return nil }

    var walletDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
    walletDictionary[ADDRESS] = address
    walletDictionary[PRIVATE_KEY] = privateKey

    return walletDictionary
}

private func initialiseJS(jsFileName: String) -> JSContext? {
    let jsContext = JSContext()
    guard let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: jsFileName, ofType: "js") else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)
        jsContext!.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
        return jsContext!
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: as of today there is a liquid core plugin available on pub https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_liquidcore

Comment: what about web?How can we use it in flutter web too?

Comment: @ajil - have you continued to use this method in the long term? was it successful in production ?

Comment: Does someone get this works? can you post the github please.

Comment: as now ,there's no MainActivity.java file ,just one MainActivity.kt and it looks like this
package com.example.chicago_app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}

Answer (score 1):

```
    Future<String> loadJS(String name) async {
  var givenJS = rootBundle.loadString('assets/$name.js');
  return givenJS.then((String js) {
    flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
      if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript(js);
      }
    });
  });
}
```