# Use npm packages in flutter mobile app webview

Tags: javascript, npm, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am working on flutter mobile app. I want to use a npm package that is built on top of web3.js and provide some extra custom functionalities. I know in flutter dart is not compiled to js. I have also played with webview plugin that accepts uri. Some of my mates were arguing that using webview we might can use the npm package. I decided to try that but I missing the entry point as I know that webview plugin accepts URI and I don't know how to tweak that to use npm package so any type of help regarding using npm in flutter mobile app is much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Use of packages like "FLUTTER NODE" or "FLUTTER CLI" may help with it. Also Flutter has its own pub named "web3dart" and "etherium" which might help you if you have an inclination towards blockchain!