# Can Node.JS integrate inside Flutter mobile application?

Tags: node.js, flutter

I created a mobile application with flutter in front end and back end with node.js but I want it to use node js in offline mode in another meaning I want host this node inside the mobile. can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

First, you'd need NodeJS itself built for you mobile platform. Only then can you even consider running the node application you've written.

Flutter is Dart and NodeJS is well, JS. You can't put them together. But if you are building a node app that builds into a static js and html, may be you can put it in a webview, which does not seem to be the case here.

You are asking to run server side code on the client itself and offline too. If the application can really be offline, I think you're better off without a backend and store everything static within the flutter app itself.

Comment: So what about this . (FromThe beginning my problem was this) I want to access my router in home with ip 192.168.1.1 i got fully permission by using API for Node.JS and works fine with my mobile while my computer work as host what if i put this API to cloud ? Can i access my router at the same time ? If yes how ?

Comment: You don't need to access the router. If you put it on the cloud, you get another static ip that you can use to access your API from your application.

Comment: Your local setup with your router is for development only. When you go into production, you need a proper server.

Comment: My API is use to configure this router that i connected via ip address .. so i used company api for in this case to configure my router with mobile application and this api as middleware .. so inside code of nodejs i wrote connect to 192.168.1.1 to config my router but i think in that case i should directly connect mobile to this static ip of API not 192.168.1.1 after that i must use static ip of cloud provider not 192.168.1.1 then i think i cant configure my router ....