# Node js Drivers on Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

I'm building an app using FlutterDart for mobile, and am integrating MongoDB for the same.

It happens that no official package is available for MongoDB for Flutter env, but they have for NodeJs.

Is there any way I could use js packages within Flutter to write database logic, more or less similar to API.

I don't really want to take the trouble to deploy the node API, but want it somewhat packaged with the app deployment itself.

Is there any suggestions you may give?

Comment: You could, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68934555/5774952). You shouldn't, because you really should not have clients directly accessing your db.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Backend-as-a-service.
for ex:- you can use firebase that offers database which is directly accessible directly from flutter app. It also provides authentication, file storage, and other services.

Also

MongoDB's Realm service provides serverless functions that can be used to interact with MongoDB. You can use Realm functions as an intermediary between your Flutter app and MongoDB.