# Flutter Web : How to run javascript using dart js

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-web

I want to use the Stripe library on the web flutter. But unfortunately, until now there is still no stripe library available for web flutter. Therefore I try to run javascript on the web flutter, where it will call the stripe-js library (https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment).

What I want to ask, first, is how to use the javascript library on web flutter? like this :

`<script src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/"> </script>`

Secondly, how do I call the javascript function on the web flutter? like this :

```
stripe
   .confirmCardPayment ('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
     payment_method: {
       card: cardElement,
       billing_details: {
         name: 'Jenny Rosen',
       },
     },
   })
   .then (function (result) {
     // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
   });
```

stripe-js docs: https://stripe.com/docs/js

Thank you

Comment: Please post a solution if you found one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap that in a global variable

```js
window.doStripePayment = (name) => {
    // Your code
}
```

certify that `app.js` is loaded with `defer`

```html
<head>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

And inside flutter do

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

js.context.callMethod('doStripePayment', ['John Doe']);
```

[Source](https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/)

Answer (score -4):

This isn't a Stripe-specific question, so I'd suggest looking into how you use a standard JS library with Flutter, i.e. [Use JS library in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330102/use-js-library-in-flutter)