# How to execute Add 2 home from dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I have created an app on all 3 platforms: iOS, Android and Web. I also have `manifest.json` and other things required for `PWA`. I have deployed it to firebase hosting. Now what I want to do is manually trigger the Add to Home screen on tap of a button. The real problem is though all the articles shows code to be paste on JS side while I have all the UI in dart so How do I listen for `beforeinstallprompt` and trigger add to home screen manually ? I'm struggling with this from last 3 days but no luck. I have this package installed `universal_html: ^1.2.3.` If anyone knows how to do this please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing those code in normal JavaScript, and then call it from Dart(flutter web).

There are many resources about that. For example, [Flutter Web : How to run javascript using dart js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591330/flutter-web-how-to-run-javascript-using-dart-js)

In addition, do not forget that, when you are writing Flutter web, you have the *full* control over the HTML/JS/CSS/Dart. Thus nothing can stop you from writing JS code :)

Comment: but in my case it's different. What we have here is a listener in javascript which will prevent default add to home screen prompt and then show a button/banner to user on Landing page in dart code. From that button I need to trigger add to home prompt again.

Comment: One more thing is web import and native import doesn't work together. The whole app is written in dart.

Comment: @RahulVyas I am confused. What about writing your JS, and then let js call dart?

Comment: yes I think we need vice versa calling. First listen to 'beforeinstallprompt' in JS and then call dart function (I'm not sure where I need to write code for it). Let me explain you the flow. 
Step 1 - listen to 'beforeinstallprompt' in JS
Step 2 - call some code in dart file on landing page or whatever page the user is in
Step 3 - Show some banner UI through dart code executed in step 2
Step 4 - from dart banner on tap of button execute add to home prompt in JS or Dart if possible

Comment: @RahulVyas then what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104432/how-to-call-a-dart-function-from-javascript

Comment: also do you know how we can detect in dart that we're running app on mobile browser not desktop browser ?

Comment: @RahulVyas then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226654/discussion-between-rahul-vyas-and-ch271828n).

Comment: please reply in chat