# How to use a JS library and a JS function in a Flutter mobile app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart

I want to use a JavaScript library in my mobile Flutter project. Here is the link for this library on github.

[Library](https://github.com/Deliaz/aboutnumber.js.git)

How can I use this library and a function(aboutnumber()) from it in my project? How can I import this library to a project and how to access its function?

Comment: Flutter uses Dart as the language and not javascript. For mobile it compiles to native code.

Comment: So, there is no way to use a js library, right?

Comment: You could look at https://pub.dev/packages/js

Comment: As I understood packages:js works only with flutter web. But I want to use the library in a mobile app. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There's just a few hundred lines of code. Probably best to just port it to Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible on any platform other than the web, as described in the [JS interop documentation](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop).

On the Web, [`package:js`](https://pub.dev/packages/js) can be used.

Answer (score 17):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js package.
It allows to evaluate pure javascript code inside mobile and desktop flutter apps. By pure, I mean the package is not a browser engine, so no web API , localstorage or another browser api are available. But you can bundle some javascript code containing javascripts libraries like moment, ajv and maybe  the one you related in your question if it relies only in javascript. The flutter_js injects into the javascript engine, things like console.log, xhr and fetch. But it is all. There is a send message channel which you could use to inject objects into the engine which you could provide objects which will be implemented and dart, but will be shared into the javascript global space.

In Flutter web, the javascript integration is possible using the package:js, mentioned in another answer.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the flutter_js package

Comment: what is your opinion on using liquidcore and platform channels as mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330102/use-js-library-in-flutter

Comment: Yes. It should work. In my flutter_js library i tried to use liquid core and I can say it works.  At the Readme in  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js there is some information about the use of JavaScript in Flutter and about alternatives also.

Comment: we can install a js package like npm? In my case I need to install some web3 packages that are ready to use only for web...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74566377/4756173), there's also [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example), which embeds a whole web view onto Flutter, and that's an official Flutter package as well.