# Is it possible to use JS visual libraries (e.g. Chart.js or D3.js) in Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-js

If it is possible, how exactly does it work? Maybe it's possible to access Flutter's [`Canvas`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) widget through JS?

My best guess for this would be the [`flutter_js`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's not possible, but in order to implement it from the start will be very hard and long work.

instead of it, I could say the better solution, is to implement what you want with javascript development, and just use the [web_view](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package and set a `WebView` of it inside your flutter application, with data exchange via the `JavascriptChannel` property.

Comment: I wish they had pictures with examples on that package. Does it look good? Anyway, thanks for mentioning that option.

Comment: There are apparently quite a few [WebView video tutorials](https://youtu.be/RA-vLF_vnng) already out there. And they look fine.