# is it possible to use Javascript librarys in flutter ? namly Sheets.js, client side, for web and mobile?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, ffi, flutter-getx

i have a cross-platform project in flutter, for web android, and ios,  i would like to add a functionality to handle two files , an xls file , and an xlsx file , the issue is the current packages are unable to handle it ( such as excel package or spreadsheet_decoder) ,

i've came accord this website "(https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/demos/mobile/flutter/) "
but flutter_js is tagged as it doesnt support web.

i would love to find a client side solution, maybe a local host server using inappview ? is that possible ?

i've tried cloud function approaches, and i took a look around for an api that does that sort of thing but i've failed so far, also those wont be client side either so..

Comment: for web you might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145501/how-to-use-a-js-library-and-a-js-function-in-a-flutter-mobile-app