# How to do batch transaction request to Ethereum in flutter?

Tags: flutter, web3js, ethers.js, web3dart, flutter-web3

What i actually need is a way to create a batch request to ethereum for my transections in flutter web.

There are 2 specific library that i am following. One of them is web3dart which i see most ppl are using. Another is Flutter_web3 which does not have any update for last 2 years so.

1. web3dart uses web3.js as a reference point. Even tho web3 does accept batch request [batchrequest](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#batchrequest). It looks like the library available for flutter does not have it.
2. flutter_web3 on the other hand uses ether.js as a reference point. Ether.js added support for batch request in v5.1.1 [JsonRpcBatchProvider](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/releases/tag/v5.1.1). Again the library available for flutter does not have it.

So my query is how one go about making batch request in flutter. It maybe i am missing or overlooked something. Please let me know if anyone have a solution or is it can not be done in Flutter atm?

Comment: This might help you: [How to use a JS library and a JS function in a Flutter mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145501/how-to-use-a-js-library-and-a-js-function-in-a-flutter-mobile-app)

Comment: If the library does not support the feature yet, you can write the feature yourself. There is nothing fundamental in Flutter and Dart that would prevent it to call Ethereum JSON-RPC endpoints like any other programming language. It might be just that the library maintainers do not have themselves demand for the feature.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa you are right. I will see if I can add the feature by myself.